# How to configure linux routing/filtering to send packets out one interface, over a bridge and into another interface on the same box

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, filtering

I'm trying to test a ethernet bridging device. I have multiple ethernet ports on a linux box. I would like to send packets out one interface, say eth0 with IP 192.168.1.1, to another interface, say eth1 with IP 192.168.1.2, on the same subnet.

I realize that normally you don't configure two interfaces on the same subnet, and if you do the kernel routes directly to each interface, rather than over the wire. How can I override this behavior, so that traffic to 192.168.1.2 goes out the 192.168.1.1 interface, and visa-versa?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why in Godsname would you want this?

Comment: I have a wireless device that bridges ethernet traffic. I have a box with several ethernet ports.  I would like to do bandwidth testing of the wireless device.

Comment: Isn't it a lot easier to just use a second device?

Comment: Scripts would be cleaner if everything happened on the same box.

Comment: If I clearly understand, then... route add -host 192.168.1.2 gw 192.168.1.1 metric 0 dev eth0. I did this few times.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/432949/routing-traffic-between-two-network-cards-through-firewall/433083#433083

Answer (score 3):

Use network namespaces. It feels like running a VM but it's not a VM, just something that look like a separate IP stack.

```
ip netns add otherhost
ip netns exec otherhost /bin/bash
```

This will open a shell under the `otherhost` network namespace. If you examine the network configuration in it, you will see that there is no interface. It's like if you were running a different host.

Now, move the `eth1` interface to the `otherhost` network namespace:

```
ip link set eth1 netns otherhost
```

Now, the `otherhost` namespace has your `eth1` interface. Configure it like you would do if it were a separate host, and do the same for `eth0` on your default network namespace. It's as simple as that.

Note that if you close all your shell to `otherhost`, the network namespace will disappear, and its interfaces will be moved back into the default network namespace.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt

> `accept_local` - BOOLEAN  Accept packets with local source addresses. In
>   combination with  suitable routing, this can be used to direct packets
>   between two   local interfaces over the wire and have them accepted
>   properly.     default FALSE

Using `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.accept_local=1`

Sends the packet over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#mark packets from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.2
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.1 -d 192.168.1.2 -j MARK --set-mark 11
#mark packets from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.1
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.2 -d 192.168.1.1 -j MARK --set-mark 12

#add routing table for 192.168.1.1 
ip ru a fwmark 11 table 11
ip r a 192.168.1.2 dev eth0  t 11

#add routing table for 192.168.1.2
ip ru a fwmark 12 table 12
ip r a 192.168.1.1 dev eth1  t 12
```

---

man ip , man iptables for more info

Comment: A little more context would help round out your answer (Pretend you don't know what the `ip` command does and briefly explain what the alphabet soup means :). In a lot of answers on the site we go out of our way to discourage people from blindly typing things they find on the internet without really understanding it -- seems fair that our answers should encourage understanding over blind "type this" solutions...

Comment: I pretend that OP already know 'man' command. why I should explain what iproute does ?

Comment: in fact it may be not full solution, will update the answer to make it worki better

Comment: Much better -- You'd be surprised how many people have not yet mastered the use of manual pages...

Comment: I know, but I still not think that you need to read documentation of core utilites for anybody. as you not need to describe printf on stackoverflow :)

Comment: It's not "what does the tool do?" that we're looking for as context, it's "Why should I use *this* tool in *this* way?" -- To extend your analogy, "Why `printf` instead of `puts`?".  Knowing "how" solves the current problem, knowing "why" means you don't have to ask a similar question tomorrow :) (If you want to kick this topic around some more I'm on chat in [The Comms Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room))

Comment: When receiving, the kernel will drop packets if their source address matches one of its own interfaces. You need to unset the `accept_local` sysctl (or something like that).